# How to verify my SSL(https) Certificate is working for Openfire?

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, openfire

I had done the following steps:

1. Create Keystore

   `$ keytool –keystore keystore –genkey –alias xyz.com -keyalg rsa -keysize 2048`
2. Generate CSR

   `$ keytool –keystore keystore –certreq –alias xyz.com –keyalg rsa -keysize 2048 –file client.csr`
3. Get Certificate from CA. It contains two certificates.

   a. ssl_certificate

   b. Intermediate certificate
4. Import signed certificate

   a. Import Intermediate Certificate

   `keytool -import -keystore keystore -file Intermediate.cer -alias xyz.com_rsa`

   b. Import SSL Certificate

   `keytool -import -keystore keystore -file ssl_certificate.cer -alias xyz.com`

Now, I had checked the signed certificate in `Openfire Admin Console`, I found a warning under `TSL/SSL Certificate > Openfire Identity Certificate Store` is

> One or more certificates are missing. Click here to generate self-signed certificates or here to import a signed certificate and its private key.

but Identity is shown a `certificate entry` status `signed`.

Now, my questions are.

1. is Certificate is successfully signed or anything needs to do?
2. How will I check that my SSL Session is working for registered domain and port in Linux Box?
3. How to verify that the https is working for Openfire?

**Note: I delete my self-signed certificate entry.**

Answer (score 0):

https://xmpp.net/ provides an online test tool for XMPP connectivity, with a strong emphasis on security. I advise that you use that.

An alternative is using openssl. Typically, XMPP servers use STARTTLS on port 5222, which you can check like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.org:5222 -starttls xmpp
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if your ssl certificate is successfully installed using this site  https://www.sslcerty.com.

you will know if your website's ssl certificate is installed properly, and also all infromation about your certificate's chain information.